# Seqeulize Foreign Keys not being created (for MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database storing users from two different platforms.

In one table, let's say we have a table called `platformA` that holds `id`, `platformAid`, `username`.

In the second table, let's say we have a table called `platformB` that holds `id`, `platformBid`, `username`, `level`.

Now, I want to create another table to "link" the two accounts together using the primary key from both platforms. The table will ideally be like so: `id`, `platformAid`, `platformBid`.

So, I have the database models defined like this

```
var platformA = db.define('platformA', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    platformAid: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    username: { type: Sequelize.CHAR }
});

var platformB = db.define('platformB', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    platformBid: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    username: { type: Sequelize.CHAR },
    level: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER }
});

var connect = db.define('connect ', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    platformAid: { 
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        refrences: {
            model: 'platformA',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    platformBid: { 
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        refrences: {
            model: 'platformB',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
});
```

As far as I know, I then need to use `belongsTo` like so

```
platformA.belongsTo(connect, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'platformAid' });
platformB.belongsTo(connect, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'platformBid' });
```

Now this code creates the tables just fine, however there's no foreign keys to be found. At this point, I probably have something backwards or am missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to create many-to-many relation between platformA and platformB? So that platformA can have many platformB, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the connection in wrong way.

```
platformA.belongsTo(connect, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'platformAid' });
```

Above code states that the field `id` in table `platformA` references table `connect`, whereas the `id` field should be a primary key of `platformA`. The `as` attribute only defines `alias` for the association, not the field.

In order to define the foreign key on `connect` table that reference models `platformA` and `platformB` you need to define the association on `connect` model

```
connect.belongsTo(platformA, { foreignKey: 'platformAid', as: 'platformA' });
```

This association states that the `platformAid` column in `connect` table references `platformA` table. Then you need to do the same with `platformB`

```
connect.belongsTo(platformB, { foreignKey: 'platformBid`, as: 'platformB' });
```

That is where my comment comes from - do you want to create a m:n relation between `platformA` and `platformB`, because that is when the join table is being used, just as in your case.

Comment: I want to link the two accounts together. So, both of the primary keys (id) will link the two tables together. Here's a quick mouse-drawn idea of what I want: https://i.imgur.com/KlKNDgP.png

Comment: I realize now I should have left out the platform ids to avoid confusion. Those platform ids are basically the id of the platform, like a user id. Like on discord, you get assigned a long id such as `97774516968648704`.

Comment: Actually, what you have is correct. At first I just didn't understand it, but that did created the foreign key the way I want it. Thanks!